# Confusion on repeated index for Einstein Summation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

The rule for Einstein notation is that the same dummy index cannot be repeated twice. However suppose I want to compute Christoeffel symbols:
$$
\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\sigma}(\partial_\beta g_{\gamma\sigma}+\partial_{\gamma}g_{\sigma\beta}-\partial_{\sigma}g_{\beta\gamma})
$$

Now if my metric is diagonal, then only the terms $\alpha = \sigma$ survive, hence we have:
$$
\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\alpha}(\partial_\beta g_{\gamma\alpha}+\partial_{\gamma}g_{\alpha\beta}-\partial_{\alpha}g_{\beta\gamma})
$$

Of course now the problem is that the index $\alpha$ is repeated three times. However, it makes perfect sense to me when I do the computation. Is there some exception to the "not repeated twice" rule?

Comment: If the metric is diagonal and constant, the correct way to write it is $g^{\alpha\beta} = \delta^{\alpha\beta}$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I was thinking of something more like the Schwarzschild metric

Answer (score 3):

The Einstein summation rule is true for tensor-equations. Once you assume a form for the metric (diagonality), the equation you get is no longer a true tensor-equation (it is only true in some coordinate-systems). This is the reason why you need to write the summation by-hand from this point on.

Comment: also $\alpha=\sigma=\lambda=\beta$ so the equation becomes:$ \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha\alpha} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\alpha}(\partial_\alpha g_{\alpha\alpha}+\partial_{\alpha}g_{\alpha\alpha}-\partial_{\alpha}g_{\alpha\alpha})$

Comment: So should it be:

$$
\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha}g^{\alpha\alpha}(\partial_{\beta}g_{\gamma\alpha} + \partial_{\gamma}g_{\alpha\beta} + \partial_{\alpha}g_{\beta\gamma})
$$

?